# What's the difference between HttpMethod and RequestType of HttpRequest?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, httphandler, httprequest

The [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest_properties.aspx) class defines two properties:

**[HttpMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.httpmethod.aspx):**

> Gets the HTTP data transfer method (such as GET, POST, or HEAD) used by the client.
>
> ```
> public string HttpMethod { get; }
> ```
>
> The HTTP data transfer method used by the client.

and **[RequestType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.requesttype.aspx)**:

> Gets or sets the HTTP data transfer method (GET or POST) used by the client.
>
> ```
> public string RequestType { get; set; }
> ```
>
> A string representing the HTTP invocation type sent by the client.

What is the difference between these two properties? When would I want to use one over the other? Which is the proper one to inspect to see what data transfer method was used by the client?

The documentation indicates that **HttpMethod** will return whatever verb was used:

> such as GET, POST, or HEAD

while the documentation on **RequestType** seems to indicate only one of two possible values:

> GET or POST

---

I tested with a random sampling of verbs, and both properties seem to support all verbs, and both return the same values:

Testing:

```
Client Used    HttpMethod    RequestType
GET            GET           GET
POST           POST          POST
HEAD           HEAD          HEAD
CONNECT        CONNECT       CONNECT
MKCOL          MKCOL         MKCOL
PUT            PUT           PUT
FOOTEST        FOOTEST       FOOTEST
```

What is the difference between:

- HttpRequest.HttpMethod
- HttpRequest.RequestType

and when should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) shows that `RequestType` calls `HttpMethod` internally. So you're *ever so slightly* better off calling `HttpMethod`. Actually I think the real reason `RequestType` exists was for backwards compatibility with classic ASP.

Comment: So you're saying **HttpMethod** is the preferred mechanism, but they're otherwise identical.

Comment: It's worth noting that, in ASP.NET Core, `RequestType` is no longer a property of the [`HttpRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest) class. So using `HttpMethod` (now simply `Method`) will probably make it easier for you when porting from Standard to Core.

Answer (score -4):

You can check below article:-

Request methods:
An HTTP request made using telnet. The request, response headers and response body are highlighted.

HTTP defines eight methods (sometimes referred to as "verbs") indicating the desired action to be performed on the identified resource. What this resource represents, whether pre-existing data or data that is generated dynamically, depends on the implementation of the server. Often, the resource corresponds to a file or the output of an executable residing on the server.

HEAD
    Asks for the response identical to the one that would correspond to a GET request, but without the response body. This is useful for retrieving meta-information written in response headers, without having to transport the entire content.

GET
    Requests a representation of the specified resource. Note that GET should not be used for operations that cause side-effects, such as using it for taking actions in web applications. One reason for this is that GET may be used arbitrarily by robots or crawlers, which should not need to consider the side effects that a request should cause. See safe methods below.

POST
    Submits data to be processed (e.g., from an HTML form) to the identified resource. The data is included in the body of the request. This may result in the creation of a new resource or the updates of existing resources or both.
PUT
    Uploads a representation of the specified resource.
DELETE
    Deletes the specified resource.
TRACE
    Echoes back the received request, so that a client can see what intermediate servers are adding or changing in the request.
OPTIONS
    Returns the HTTP methods that the server supports for specified URL. This can be used to check the functionality of a web server by requesting '*' instead of a specific resource.
CONNECT
    Converts the request connection to a transparent TCP/IP tunnel, usually to facilitate SSL-encrypted communication (HTTPS) through an unencrypted HTTP proxy.[5]
PATCH
    Is used to apply partial modifications to a resource.[6]

HTTP servers are required to implement at least the GET and HEAD methods[7] and, whenever possible, also the OPTIONS method.[citation needed]
Safe methods

Some methods (for example, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS and TRACE) are defined as safe, which means they are intended only for information retrieval and should not change the state of the server. In other words, they should not have side effects, beyond relatively harmless effects such as logging, caching, the serving of banner advertisements or incrementing a web counter. Making arbitrary GET requests without regard to the context of the application's state should therefore be considered safe.

By contrast, methods such as POST, PUT and DELETE are intended for actions which may cause side effects either on the server, or external side effects such as financial transactions or transmission of email. Such methods are therefore not usually used by conforming web robots or web crawlers, which tend to make requests without regard to context or consequences.

Despite the prescribed safety of GET requests, in practice their handling by the server is not technically limited in any way, and careless or deliberate programming can just as easily (or more easily, due to lack of user agent precautions) cause non-trivial changes on the server. This is discouraged, because it can cause problems for Web caching, search engines and other automated agents, which can make unintended changes on the server.

Comment: You should add the link and qute only the important parts

Comment: This answer does not answer the original question - it just talks about HTTP methods in general.